# Xcode -- embed one static library inside another one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

Is it possible to do this in such a way that the parent project does not need any settings that refer to the sub-library -- only to the parent library?

(For example, I want header search paths to be picked up automatically).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a Framework, not actually a static library ( You will always need the symbol references aka headers when you use static libraries )

The solution that Apple gave us, is Frameworks.

You can checkout this GitHub [project](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework#readme) which contains an Xcode 4 template for creating iOS frameworks again.

Good luck!